# Bad/illegal format of URL error while using curl to gather data

Tags: json, curl, httprequest, client-server, rest

I am trying to gather data from an atlassian confluence wiki page through an http request using the curl command that utilizes REST-API. The website I am trying to access is maintained by my company's server. The command I am currently using is:

```
curl -v -w -u admin:admin https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/494966598 | python -mjson.tool
```

In place of admin:admin I type my username which is my email then a colon and my password so for eg. ridwan.regression@ai.com:thisispassword@ai I know that the link is correct as when I click "https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/494966598" it directly takes me to the page which gets displayed in a JSON format with all the information but when I try to enter that command in the terminal I get an error saying.

```
Closing Connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
......
....
.....
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that author has asked same question by atlassian forum and got some hints there:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/curl-http-request-returning-bad-illegal-format-or-missing-URL/qaq-p/1655207

As summary of given hints: it was proposed to specify explicitly in the request the expected output format (i.e. -H "Content-Type: application/json" ).
Also it was recommended to use proper authentication mechanism.

On top of that following root causes are possible:

- real URL contains space-symbols, which being properly handled by copy/paste to browser url field, but are not allowed as part of url by curl (i.e. they should be replaced depending on use-case by %20 or by + )
- there is/are some special (not ascii) characters in the URL, which causes similar behavior as with spaces

In general - it could be useful to:

- encapsulate the URL into double quotes (i.e. "your_url")
- try to encode used URL according to html url standard and see whether some symbols being replaced there (i.e. such symbols are causing the problem)